# Usage of a common generic default implementation for refined Factories

Tags: java, generics

I have the following problem:

There is a generic Factory interface

```
interface Factory<T> {
  T create();
}
```

Now I have two classes T1 and T2, where T2 is a refinement of T1

```
class T1 {
}

class T2 extends T1 {
}
```

and two factories for those types:

```
interface T1Factory extends Factory<T1> {
  public T1 create();
}

interface T2Factory extends Factory<T2> {
  public T2 create();
}
```

For those factories a default implementation will be provided via Generics:

```
class DefaultFactory<T, F extends Factory<T>> implements Factory<T> {
  private F factory;
  ...
  public T create()
  {
    return factory.create();
  }
}
```

that should be used to implement factories for T1 and T2.

```
class DefaultT1Factory extends DefaultFactory<T1,T1Factory> {
}

class DefaultT2Factory extends DefaultFactory<T2,T2Factory> {
}
```

Up to here it works fine. Now the problem.
Because T2 is a refinement of T1 the Factory for T2 should be usable also as factory for T1.

This requires T2Factory to be derived from T1Factory. If I do this I cannot use the DefaultFactory class to implement the DefaultT2Factory, because T2Factory is no Factory<T2>.
If I add this relationship to the extends clause of T2Factory I got the error that the interface Factory is used more than once. But I need the Factory interface to be able to use the create method in the default implementation.

From the point of method signatures everything is fine. As a consequence I've to duplicate the implementation of the default implementation into the to factory implementation. In my case this coding is quite large and I want to avoid code duplication.

Any idea how to circumvent this problem.

Comment: Why should the factory for `T2` be usable also as a factory for `T1` ?

Comment: Because T2 can also be used like T1s. Therefore wherevery I need a factory for T1  I want to be able to pass a Factory for T2 also.

Comment: Basically I just could write something like this:
    interface T2Factory extends T1Factory {
       T2 create();
    }
Overwriting the create methods refines the return type and everything works fine. Unfortunately then I cannot use the default implementation shown above for both interfaces T1Factory and T2Factory.
If I could additionally extend again from Factory&lt;T2&gt; it would work, but this is not possible in Java. The method signature would match perfectly, becaiuse only the return type is refined.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant

Because T2 is a refinement of T1 the Factory for T1 should be usable also as factory for T2.
A factory of T1 should not be used as a factory of T2 because T1 IS NOT T2. However T2 IS T1, so a factory for T2 can be safetly used as a factory of T1(or treated as a factory of T1)

```
   public interface T1Factory<J extends T1> extends Factory<T1> {
             public T1 create();
        }
```

Now when you implement this interface, its cool to say something like

```
public class Foo implements T1Factory<T2> {
         public T1 create(){
                    .....
          }
 }
```

Now basically the interface can be parameterized with any type that extends or is T1. In this case you stated you wanted to take advantage of the T2 is a T1 relationship.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wildcard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) to define something like *Factory of T or any subtype of T*. If you change signature of `DefaultFactory` to

```
class DefaultFactory<T, F extends Factory<? extends T>> implements Factory<T> {
```

Then you should be able to have `DefaultFactory<T1, T2Factory>`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution, not really nice, but it seems to work. The answer before is nearly working, but use *super* instead of *extends*.
The important point is just to be able to reuse the implementation.

This should be possible when relaxing the type constraint for the factory element by using super.

```
class DefaultFactory<T, F extends Factory<? super T>> {
  private F factory;

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public T create()
  {
    return (T)factory.create();
  }
}
```

The price is the type unsafetyness when calling the create method, which required an unsafe type cast. But the rest seems to work as expected.

*T2Factory* thereby has to extend *T1Factory*. Then it is unfortunately not a *Factory<T2>*, but this was required only for being able to call the create method in the default implementation returning the correct type. And for this purpose it is sufficient to be a *Factory<T1>* (which causes the required type cast).